# Parse and Organize GovTrack API JSON data

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I have the JSON data from an API call to GovTrack (https://www.govtrack.us/api/v2/role?state=ne&current=true) in a JSONObject.

I'm having trouble navigating the JSON data and organizing it in a meaningful way.  My count is 2 (and I think it should be 5, as there are 5 actual "people" returned from the API call.  Plus the meta tag 'total_count' is 5 as well).  Also, I'm blowing up when trying to access "firstName" and "lastName".

Any help getting the correct data grouped and possibly organizing it into objects by person would be great.

My code:

```
    public void getRepJSONdata(){
    try{
        JSONArray allRepsResults = allRepData.getJSONArray("objects");
        for (int i = 0; i < allRepsResults.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject currentItem = allRepsResults.getJSONObject(i);
            String firstName = currentItem.getString("firstName");
            String lastName = currentItem.getString("lastName");

        }
    }catch (Exception ex){
        //trace out bad stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below code:

```
public void getRepJSONdata(){
        try{
            JSONArray allRepsResults = allRepData.getJSONArray("objects");
            for (int i = 0; i < allRepsResults.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject currentItem = allRepsResults.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONObject person = currentItem.getJSONObject("person");
                String firstName = person.getString("firstName");
                String lastName = person.getString("lastName");

            }
        }catch (Exception ex){
            //trace out bad stuff
        }
    }
```

Comment: You got it, too easy :)  I didn't realize I needed to setup another JSONObject and go that extra level deep.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What helps to sort out new JSON strings you don't really know is to use a JSON parser:

- http://json.parser.online.fr/
- http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

The correct answer was already posted by bhavesh N, but I thought this could be useful.